# How can I extract the max value out of multiple text files within a directory

Tags: numpy, file, max, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import os
import glob

dirname="x"
ext=('y.dat')
for files in os.listdir(dirname):
    if files.endswith(ext):
        temp=np.loadtxt(files)
        print(np.max(temp))
    else:
        continue
```

once i create a loop to go through the directory, how do I get it to extract and print the max values from the specified text files?

Comment: remove the `else`, it is useless. Is your loop printing something? What's your output?

Comment: I was hoping it would print the max value from each data file within the directory. Ideally I would like a new data frame that consists of just the max value from each file in the directory.

Comment: Even after I remove the else, it give me an error stating that a certain data file is not found, even though the data file is there and the path is unchanged. 
The error is in the line temp=np.loadtxt(files).
If I remove this line and try print(np.loadtxt(files)) or print(np.max(files)) the same error persists.

Comment: Please edit the question and write the error that this script rises.